# writexl 1.4.1 bug: empty date entry becomes nan(snan)

Tags: r, timestamp, writexl

After reading (readxl) and writing (writexl) a xlsx file with R, an empty entry changes to "nan(snan)". See attachment: Change from [before reading and writing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpybG.png)

to  [after reading and writing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Le3D.png)

I believe that I hadn't this problem before I updated to writexl 1.4.1. Any ideas?

Code:

require(writexl)

require(readxl)

data<-read_excel("test_file.xlsx")

data$ERF_DATUM[3]<-NA

write_xlsx(data, "test_file.xlsx", col_names = TRUE, format_headers = TRUE)

Comment: Changing back to writexl 1.4.0 solves the problem.

Comment: I also have this problem. Did you report it to their github as an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved in 1.4.2 which is now available in CRAN